# Proving: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2}=\frac{1}{2-c}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

> let f be a function three times differentiable on $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$ such that $f(x)> 0, f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)>0$ for $x>0$ prove that if:
> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)f'''(x)}{(f''(x))^2}=c ,\quad  c\neq 1$$
> So:
> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2}=\frac{1}{2-c}$$

using the hospital rule we get: $(1)\quad $
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)f'''(x)}{(f''(x))^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{f'(x)}{xf''(x)}\right)=c$$
proof $(1)$:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{f'(x)}{xf''(x)}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(x-\frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}\right)}{x'}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)f'''(x)}{(f''(x))^2}=c$$
So we find : $$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f'(x)}{xf''(x)}=1-c$$

This is what I found now, how can I use this result in finding the required or is there any other way to prove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is a simple case of L'Hospital's Rule. Let $g(x) =(f'(x)) ^2/f''(x)$ and we need to prove that $f(x) /g(x) \to (2-c)^{-1}$ or $g(x) /f(x) \to 2 - c$.

Convince yourself (not difficult) that $f(x) \to\infty $ and hence the L'Hospital's Rule applies on $g/f$. Note that $$g' (x) =\frac{2f'(x)(f''(x))^2-(f'(x))^2f'''(x)} {(f''(x)) ^2}$$ and hence $$\frac{g' (x)} {f'(x)} =2 - \frac{f'(x) f''' (x)} {(f''(x)) ^2}\to 2 - c$$ It follows that $g/f$ also tends to $2-c$. If $c\neq 2$ then $f/g\to (2-c)^{-1}$.

Comment: nice solution !!